# Django reverts to default urls

Tags: django

I'm working with Django 1.6.4 and I've constructed a login system that appears to be working up until the back button is pressed in the browser. The URL giving me fits is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login`. Here is my project URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'', include('apps.mylogin.urls')),
)
```

(Before any of you Django veterans point out the empty regex pattern :) – I've tried a number of different ones that have been suggested on the interwebs: (`'^', '^$'`), and even tried moving the app's URLconf into the project's URLconf and all of them seem to yield this error. Of course if you detect shenanigans in this code, feel free to point it out, I like best practices :D)

The URLconf contained in the include is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('apps.mylogin.views',
    url(r'^login/$', 'login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logged_in/$', 'logged_in', name='logged_in'),
)
```

Let's say I land on the login page and I don't enter any information, I just click submit; the LoginForm class that I've created will (during the clean method) return a `raise ValidationError`. Everything works as expected: all the appropriate errors are displayed to the user and life is peachy... until I hit the back button. It is at this point I'm presented with a captured 404 page that says it was a GET request sent to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login` with the following read out:

```
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^account/
The current URL, login/, didn't match any of these.
```

I'm assuming these URLs are some part of a 'base' set defined by Django; which is well enough and all, but I'm quite curious as to why it appears to have forgot my URLs and suddenly can't find the location I was just at.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if there is any additional information required please let me know and I'll attempt to edit this question to reflect it.

Comment: There are no "base" urls, defined by django. Everything defined ROOT_URLCONF is all you get.

First, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login` should fail, because you have only `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/` defined as login url (with trailing slash).

Second, just side information, never use `$` in regex which points to included urls. `$` matches the end of string, which means that if regex matches, anything will be left for include.

Last, please check again that the right urlconf is used. There shouldn't be any `admin` or `accounts` unless you define it.

Comment: That's why it's so weird to me, ^accounts/ isn't defined anywhere in my project. I've done a search directory-wide for 'account' and nothing appears. As far as I know, root_url is set to myproject.urls.

Comment: Could you push your source tree to public repository?

Comment: Actually, I don't think I'll have to do that... After returning home I copied the project to another box and decided I'd do some deep debugging and... well... it worked "as-is". :-/ Apparently there is something conflicting on my laptop that is causing it to misbehave in ways I can't fathom. Thanks for the help elvard! :)

Answer (score 0):

After yet additional testing and thought on the matter it appears that there is a conflict of caching mechanisms. It appears the conflict is produced when using certain Safari extensions, causing what appeared to be an injection of information; when in reality it was using code from several tutorials that had run before it.

I've arrived at this conclusion by testing Chrome, Firefox and Safari all without any extensions or enhancements beyond their default configuration. It is only when I return to Safari and enable a specific extension (and what is more absurd is that this particular extension does not inhibit my desktop ... it might be likely that there are additional extensions working in conjunction to cause this) that I receive the captured 404 error along with the seemingly injected `^account/`.

Comment: I don't think that you've found the real source of problem. Django is server side application, it interacts with your browser over HTTP protocol only. Browser, not even any extension, can't "add" urls to your django app.

There might be browser's cache, redirects, anything which looks suspicious, but your browser definitely doesn't alter your python code.

Comment: Exactly, sorry I've not been back on to reflect this in awhile — vacation and all. :) I got to thinking about it actually on the drive and concluded that it might be some caching that is getting borked via one of the said extensions. I'll adjust it to reflect this information soon.